# React JS axios error Request failed with status code 500 using Django REST Framework

Tags: reactjs, json, api, django-rest-framework, axios

I need data from 4 table in same output json from Django Rest API.

Models.py

```
class T(model.Model)
 book = models.ForeignKey(
        'b.B',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
 user = models.ForeignKey('a.U', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=[('0', 'DRAFT'),('1', 'PUBLISH')], default=0)

class B(model.Model)
 title = models.CharField(max_length=256, default='TITLE')
 user = models.ForeignKey('a.U', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 category = models.ForeignKey('c.C', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class U(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Views.py

@api_view(['GET'])

```
def collect(request):
    data = T.objects.select_related('b').filter(status=1)
    list = []
    for row in data:
        list.append(
                {
                    'id':row.book.id, 
                    'book_title': row.b.title,
                    'author': row.b.u.name,
                    'category': row.b.c.name,
                }
            )
    return Response(
      data = list,
      status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
    )
```

Output in Postman

[image]

But when calling the API in React.js using Axios, the data doesn't show and get error.

```
 the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

This is a code in React.js

```
import useAuth from '../../hooks/useAuth';
import axios from '../../api/axios';

const Library = () => {
    const { auth, setAuth } = useAuth();
    const [dataKoleksi, setProjek] = useState([])
    const getProjek = async() => {
        try {
            let response = await axios.get('https://app.com/api/collect', 
                {
                    headers: { 
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization' : `Bearer ${auth.access}` 
                    },
                    withCredentials: true
                }
            )
            setProjek(response.data)
            setFoundBook(response.data)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getProjek();
    }, [])
```

My question is why in React.js data can't show and got error, but it's success when try to testing get data in Postman.

Comment: Hi, Can you please paste postman screenshot here

Comment: @sgrmhdk done, i have edited